# Renombrar etiqueta grafica por gráfica

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

Veo que hay una etiqueta que se debería renombrar. La etiqueta es [graficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graficas), y debería renombrarse por [gráficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gr%c3%a1ficas), Ya que hay otras etiquetas que también tienen tilde, como por ejemplo, [validación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validaci%c3%b3n).

Esta etiqueta no está relacionada con las placas de video ni con los efectos especiales de un videojuego, sino con manipulación de imágenes o estadísticas de oficina.

Ejemplo: [Agregar indicador de aumento o disminución de datos en d3.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23619/agregar-indicador-de-aumento-o-disminuci%C3%B3n-de-datos-en-d3-js)

Frases, con tilde y sin tilde:

> Sin tilde: Tú graficas esa tabla.
>
> Con tilde: Las gráficas de esa tabla me sirven.

Comment: Son dos etiquetas muy ambiguas, me parece mejor eliminarlas.

Comment: @rnd Si es ese el caso, y la etiqueta no es de utilidad, que sea eliminada entonces. De lo contrario, me gustaría que la renombren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suscribo que el español debe ser impecable. Tilde donde va tilde. Virgulilla donde va Virgulilla, Diéresis donde va Diéresis, etc.

Ahora -corrijan me si me equivoco- una etiqueta como [gráficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gr%c3%a1ficas) puede ser aplicada a muchas cosas muy diferentes; por eso, no sirve como etiqueta.

Cito tu pregunta, supongamos que ponemos esto en la orientación de uso:

> Esta etiqueta no está relacionada con las placas de video ni con los efectos especiales de un videojuego, sino con manipulación de imágenes o estadísticas de oficina.

¿Para que nos sirve tener una etiqueta **que agrupa** preguntas sobre: "manipulación de imágenes" y "estadísticas de oficina"?

Creo que las etiquetas sirven para: 1. Leer el *feed rss*; 2. Buscar/Navegar por un tema especifico; Si la etiqueta cubre temas tan diferentes, no es una buena etiqueta y -quizá- lo mejor seria eliminarla; Ademas muchos usuarios nuevos la van a usar sin siquiera saber que tiene una orientación de uso y **en lugar de introducir orden al sitio, introduce caos**.

Mi conclusión:

### Eliminemos este tipo de etiquetas.