# Casos generales de posibles cambios de etiquetas

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

A raíz de la pregunta que hice recientemente:

- [¿Qué hacer con las etiquetas [concatenación] y [concatenacion]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3928/fusionar-etiquetas-concatenaci%c3%b3n-y-concatenacion?fbclid=IwAR2OFzOvOS6YlNlkjhTjtXATdfbctibp3P_gW_KQhmn0qBMEuzFAA7-XssE)

Quiero ampliar el caso y presentar una lista de etiquetas. Esto lo separo en tres grupos.

- Le faltan tildes
- Están en inglés pero deberían estar en español
- Están en español pero deberían estar en inglés

## Falta de tildes

> Una pregunta tiene las etiquetas `pipe`, `tuberias`, `semaforos`, y dos más. Se puede simplificar como:
>
> - [semaforos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semaforos) ([una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207108/sem%C3%A1foro-con-hilos-en-java)) → [semáforos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sem%c3%a1foros)
> - [tuberias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuberias) (4 preguntas) y [pipe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe) (15 preguntas)  → [tuberías](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuber%c3%adas)

- [graficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graficas) (24 preguntas) → [gráficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gr%c3%a1ficas) Discutido: [Renombrar etiqueta grafica por gráfica](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/997/renombrar-etiqueta-grafica-por-gr%c3%a1fica)
- [sesion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sesion) (9 preguntas) y [session](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) (144 preguntas) → [sesiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sesiones) (48 preguntas)
- [paginacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginacion) (24 preguntas) y [paginado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginado) (2 preguntas) → [paginación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginaci%c3%b3n) (7 preguntas)
- [dialogo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogo) (21 preguntas) y [dialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialog) (19 preguntas) → [diálogo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/di%c3%a1logo)
- [busquedas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/busquedas) (9 preguntas) y [find](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find) (25 preguntas) → [búsquedas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b%c3%basquedas)
- [agrupacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agrupacion) (5 preguntas) y [group-by](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group-by) (25 preguntas) → [agrupación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agrupaci%c3%b3n)

> - [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo) (124 preguntas) y [google-hoja-de-calculo-api-v3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo-api-v3) ([una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166588/dejo-de-funcionar-la-integraci%C3%B3n-de-php-con-googlespreadsheet))
>   → [google-hoja-de-cálculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-c%c3%a1lculo)

- [metodos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metodos) (125 preguntas) → [método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m%c3%a9todo) (13 preguntas)
- [arbol-binario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arbol-binario) (15 preguntas) → [árboles-binarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a1rboles-binarios) (28 preguntas)
- [menu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) (135 preguntas) → [menú](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/men%c3%ba)
- [encriptacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encriptacion) (69 preguntas) → [encriptación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encriptaci%c3%b3n)
- [buenas-practicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buenas-practicas) (38 preguntas) → [buenas-prácticas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buenas-pr%c3%a1cticas)
- [programacion-bajo-nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programacion-bajo-nivel) (38 preguntas) → [programación-bajo-nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n-bajo-nivel)
- [aplicacion-escritorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacion-escritorio) (24 preguntas) → [aplicación-escritorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicaci%c3%b3n-escritorio)
- [ofuscacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ofuscacion) (3 preguntas) → [ofuscación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ofuscaci%c3%b3n)
- [compilacion-cruzada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compilacion-cruzada) (2 preguntas) → [compilación-cruzada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compilaci%c3%b3n-cruzada)
- [metodologia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metodologia) (2 preguntas) → [metodología](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metodolog%c3%ada)
- [calculo-relacional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculo-relacional) (2 preguntas) → [cálculo-relacional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%c3%a1lculo-relacional)
- [prediccion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prediccion) ([una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200028/hacer-la-predicci%C3%B3n-en-python-de-3-columnas-a-partir-de-un-csv)) → [predicción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/predicci%c3%b3n)

## Del inglés al español

> Tener cuidado con estas etiquetas, podrían no ser lo mismo:
> [shell](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) (131 preguntas), [línea-de-comandos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/l%c3%adnea-de-comandos) (30 preguntas) y [consola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consola) (105 preguntas)
> → [terminal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal) (62 preguntas)

- [db](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db) (43 preguntas) y [bd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bd) (9 preguntas) → [base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos) (1365 preguntas)
- [async](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async) (8 preguntas) y [asincronico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asincronico) (2 preguntas) → [asincronismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asincronismo) (22 preguntas)

> Agregué a una pregunta la etiqueta `clausuras`, sin saber que existía `closures`, pero pienso que la etiqueta principal tendría que estar en español.
>
> - [closures](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures) (6 preguntas) → [clausuras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clausuras) ([una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-las-clausuras-en-javascript))

- [dimension](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension) (3 preguntas) → [dimensiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensiones)
- [fonts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fonts) (26 preguntas) → [tipografía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tipograf%c3%ada) (3 preguntas)
- [animation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation) (12 preguntas) → [animación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animaci%c3%b3n) (49 preguntas)
- [mobile](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) (44 preguntas) → [programación-móvil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n-m%c3%b3vil) (52 preguntas)
- [gui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui) (68 preguntas) → [interfaz-gráfica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfaz-gr%c3%a1fica) (52 preguntas)
- [path](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path) (53 preguntas) → [rutas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rutas) (54 preguntas)
- [input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) (123 preguntas) → [entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entrada) (13 preguntas)
- [event](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event) (18 preguntas) → [eventos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventos) (153 preguntas)
- [object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object) (113 preguntas) → [objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objeto) (78 preguntas)
- [class](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) (63 preguntas) → [clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clase) (147 preguntas)
- [server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) (134 preguntas) → [servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servidor) (71 preguntas)
- [service](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) (42 preguntas) → [servicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicio) (53 preguntas)
- [function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) (81 preguntas) → [funciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/funciones) (399 preguntas)

## Del español al inglés

- [correo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/correo) (42 preguntas) → [email](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) (226 preguntas)
- [cadenas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cadenas) (13 preguntas) → [string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) (495 preguntas)

Comment: Muy buena iniciativa. Habría que mirar tranquilamente caso a caso. Para los casos en que se trata de un tema de acentuación, yo directamente renombraría la etiqueta, sin necesidad de crear sinónimo especialmente cuando la tilde está al final. Me explico, si existe _sesion_ sin tilde y la renombramos a _sesión_ con, cuando alguien empiece a teclear _ses..._ el sistema ya la recomendará la que tiene tilde.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con poner [tag:find] como sinónimo de [tag:búsqueda]. `find` es un comando utilizado por ejemplo en la línea de comandos.

Comment: @fedorqui Cierto, la etiqueta [tag:búsqueda] abarcaría cosas diferentes, quizás a los buscadores web. Ahora veo que **find** significa **encontrar** y no **buscar**.

Comment: el caso shell, terminal, consola... mejor debatirlo a parte, pues hay bastante matiz

Comment: Siendo así, dejaré de leer la pregunta. Ya veré que parte mi comentario tendría sentido agregar a la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pongo una respuesta para ir actualizando según se vaya evolucionando. Recomiendo trabajar en ello teniendo en cuenta que:

- Si editamos una pregunta, hagámoslo editando también título y cuerpo para que valga la pena haberlo hecho ([Al preguntar o editar escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83))
- **Dejemos para los moderadores la tarea de cambiar las etiquetas con muchas preguntas en que no haya discusión y se necesite solamente cambiar el nombre**: ellos pueden cambiar el nombre de una etiqueta muy fácilmente. Así no tendremos que editar un montón de preguntas de golpe y no ensuciaremos la pantalla de inicio con multitud de ediciones.

## Tildes de sobra

> - ❌ [async](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async) (8 preguntas), [asincrónico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asincr%c3%b3nico) (18 preguntas)  <s>y [asincronico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asincronico) (2 preguntas)</s>
>     → [asincronismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asincronismo) (22 preguntas)

## Falta de tildes

- ✅ <s>[semaforos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semaforos) → [semáforos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sem%c3%a1foros)</s>
- ✅ <s>[tuberias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuberias) (4 preguntas) → [pipe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe) (15 preguntas)</s>
- ✅[graficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graficas) (24 preguntas) → [gráficas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gr%c3%a1ficas) Discutido: [Renombrar etiqueta grafica por gráfica](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/997/renombrar-etiqueta-grafica-por-gr%c3%a1fica) se decidió eliminar esta etiqueta
- ✅ <s>[sesion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sesion) (9 preguntas) y ❌ [session](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) (144 preguntas) → [sesiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sesiones) (48 preguntas)</s>
- ✅[paginacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginacion) (24 preguntas) <s>y [paginado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginado) (2 preguntas)</s> → [paginación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginaci%c3%b3n) (7 preguntas)
- ✅[dialogo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialogo) (21 preguntas) y [dialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialog) (19 preguntas) → [diálogo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/di%c3%a1logo)
- ✅[busquedas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/busquedas) (9 preguntas) y ❌ [find](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find) → [búsquedas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b%c3%basquedas)
- ✅ <s>[agrupacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agrupacion) (5 preguntas) y ❌ [group-by](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group-by) (25 preguntas) → [agrupación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agrupaci%c3%b3n)</s>
- ✅[google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo) (124 preguntas)  → [google-hoja-de-cálculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-c%c3%a1lculo)
- ✅[metodos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metodos) (125 preguntas) → [método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m%c3%a9todo) (13 preguntas)
- ✅[arbol-binario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arbol-binario) (15 preguntas) → [árboles-binarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%c3%a1rboles-binarios) (28 preguntas)
- ✅[menu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) (135 preguntas) → [menú](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/men%c3%ba)
- ✅[encriptacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encriptacion) (69 preguntas) → [encriptación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encriptaci%c3%b3n)
- ✅[buenas-practicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buenas-practicas) (38 preguntas) → [buenas-prácticas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buenas-pr%c3%a1cticas)
- ✅[programacion-bajo-nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programacion-bajo-nivel) (38 preguntas) → [programación-bajo-nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n-bajo-nivel)
- ✅[aplicacion-escritorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicacion-escritorio) (24 preguntas) → [aplicación-escritorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicaci%c3%b3n-escritorio)
- ✅ <s>[ofuscacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ofuscacion) (3 preguntas) → [ofuscación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ofuscaci%c3%b3n)</s>
- ✅ <s>[compilacion-cruzada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compilacion-cruzada) (2 preguntas) → [compilación-cruzada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compilaci%c3%b3n-cruzada)</s>
- ✅ <s>[metodologia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metodologia) (2 preguntas) → [metodología](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metodolog%c3%ada)</s>
- ✅ <s>[calculo-relacional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculo-relacional) (2 preguntas) → [cálculo-relacional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%c3%a1lculo-relacional)</s>
- ✅ <s>[prediccion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prediccion) → [predicción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/predicci%c3%b3n)</s>

## Del inglés al español

- ✅[db](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db) (43 preguntas) y [bd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bd) (9 preguntas) → [base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos) (1365 preguntas) (añadido sinónimo también)
- ✅ <s>[closures](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closures) (6 preguntas) → [clausuras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clausuras)</s>
- ✅ <s>[dimension](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension) (3 preguntas) → [dimensiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensiones)</s> ELIMINADA
- ✅[fonts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fonts) (26 preguntas) → [tipografía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tipograf%c3%ada) (3 preguntas)(añadido sinónimo también)
- ✅[animation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation) (12 preguntas) → [animación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animaci%c3%b3n) (49 preguntas)
- ✅[mobile](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) (44 preguntas) → [programación-móvil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n-m%c3%b3vil) (52 preguntas)(añadido sinónimo también)
- ✅[gui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui) (68 preguntas) → [interfaz-gráfica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfaz-gr%c3%a1fica) (52 preguntas)(añadido sinónimo también)
- ✅[path](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path) (53 preguntas) → [rutas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rutas) (54 preguntas)(añadido sinónimo también)
- ✅[input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) (123 preguntas) → [entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entrada) (13 preguntas)
- ✅[event](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event) (18 preguntas) → [eventos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventos) (153 preguntas)
- ❌ [object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object) (113 preguntas) → [objeto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objeto) (78 preguntas)
- ❌ [class](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) (63 preguntas) → [clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clase) (147 preguntas)
- ✅[server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) (134 preguntas) → [servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servidor) (71 preguntas)
- ✅[service](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) (42 preguntas) → [servicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicio) (53 preguntas)(añadido sinónimo también)
- ❌ [function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) (81 preguntas) → [funciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/funciones) (399 preguntas)

## Del español al inglés

- ✅[correo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/correo) (42 preguntas) → [email](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) (226 preguntas)(añadido sinónimo también)
- [cadenas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cadenas) (13 preguntas) → ❌ [string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) (495 preguntas)

Comment: No se si [tag:async] se deba traducir, ya que es [parte del lenguaje en JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), y si no me equivoco también [forma parte del universo de c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: @KacosPro Se podría cambiar [tag:asincronico] por [tag:asincronismo] y no cambiar [tag:async]

Comment: @ArtEze si, de acuerdo, pero tal vez deberíamos agregar su descripción de uso para que se entienda que solamente se debe utilizar para problemas con esas funciones

Comment: qué buena idea @ArtEze lo del iconito verde

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con tuberias.. No existe el concepto tuberias en sistemas. Son pipes, y no son tubos..

Comment: @gbianchi yo en la carrera de informática sí estudié explícitamente _tuberías_.

Comment: suena horrible @fedorqui.. :p

Comment: @gbianchi lo sé : ) Por suerto usábamos _garbage collector_ y no alguna traducción jeje

Comment: Sugiero darle prioridad a la revisión de [tag:funciones] y de [tag:string] que son las etiquetas con mayor número de preguntas y cuya orientación de uso tiene mucho margen de mejora.

Comment: @Rubén ¿por qué _prioridad_? Las más grandes pueden hacerlas los moderadores, como apuntaba al principio de la respuesta. No hace falta que editemos centenares de preguntas cuando los moderadores lo pueden hacer en un minutillo. Eso sí, comparto totalmente lo de mejorar su orientación de uso.

Comment: @fedorqui Me refiero a discutir que se va a hacer con ellas. En mi respuesta menciono que considero que no deberían marcarse como sinónimos ciertas etiquetas, incluyendo las dos que mencioné, bueno una explícitamente (`string`)y la otra indirectamente `function`/`funciones`

Comment: @Rubén de acuerdo, faltaba contexto.

Comment: @ArtEze lo de [tag:gráficas] veo que en la discusión que enlazas se optó por eliminarla, ¿no?

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, así es.

Comment: @fedorqui con los casos de X  qué hago?  y en la seccion de Ingles->Español,  acordamos dejarlo en inglés ?

Comment: @lois6b las de X yo las dejaría como están. Son las que comentaba Rubén en su respuesta. Por otro lado, veo que cosas como [tag:fonts] las has renombrado a [tag:tipografía] (¡genial!) pero sin crear sinónimo. Creo que sería útil que se crearan, para evitar que vuelvan a crearse. En general, yo creo que sería útil en todas aquellas que la diferencia no es de una tilde (sesion - sesión), sino de algo más representativo y que, por tanto, la gente pueda volver a crear. ¡Muchas gracias crack por el currazo!

Comment: @fedorqui si, dudaba en el sinónimo. Añadidos

Comment: @lois6b ¡gracias! Iría bien también con [tag:mobile] -> [tag:programación-móvil], [tag:gui] -> [tag:interfaz-gráfica], [tag:path] -> [tag:rutas], [tag:service] -> [tag:servicios]. Finalmente, las de la sección "español al inglés", solamente haría falta meter [tag:correo] dentro de [tag:email].

Comment: Listo, Calisto :P Faltaria algo más? o ponemos status completed

Comment: @lois6b a mí me parece como que han venido los Reyes Magos, así que no puedo pedir más :D A ver qué dice ArtEze.

Comment: @lois6b Falta hacer sinónimo asincrónico y asincronismo, quedando como principal, asincronismo.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Qué opinan? ¿Tienen que estar separadas asincrónico y asincronismo o como sinónimos?

Comment: @ArtEze a mí me resulta curioso que exista tanto _asincrónico_ como _asincronismo_. Yo optaría por dejar una (probablemente [tag:asincronismo]) y definiría la otra como sinónima, más que nada para evitar que vuelvan a divergir.

Answer (score 2):

No deberíamos marcar como sinónimo etiquetas en inglés de una etiqueta en español cuando la etiqueta en inglés podría referirse a un comando, tipo de dato o palabra reservada de un lenguaje o plataforma, por ejemplo,

- [class](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class)
- [find](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find) (mencionada por fedorqui en un comentario a la pregunta)
- [function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function)
- [group-by](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group-by)
- [object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object)
- [session](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session)
- [string](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)

En su lugar, en los casos que así fuera necesario, debería mejorarse la orientación de uso y en el wiki distinguir cuando usar la etiqueta "en inglés" y cuando la etiqueta *en español*.

Por ejemplo, en los casos de [lenguaje-agnóstico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agn%c3%b3stico) deberían usar las etiquetas en español.

Comment: Cierto, habría que ver cada pregunta si se ajusta a tal etiqueta.

Comment: @ArtEze De acuerdo, pero lo primero es tener una buena orientación de uso, particularmente de las principales etiquetas

Comment: ¿y de [tag:input] a [tag:entrada] qué opinas?

Comment: @ArtEze Por el momento no recuerdo donde se usa `input` como comando/tipo de dato/palabra reservada. ¿y tú?

Comment: En _HTML_ hay una etiqueta llamada `input`.

Comment: @ArtEze No estaba contemplando las etiquetas de HTML. En cualquier caso, no se me ocurre como hacer que [tag:input] no sea una meta-etiqueta.

Comment: La etiqueta [tag:cadenas] tendría que pasar al inglés porque la palabra `cadena` no significa nada, por sí solo es una lista de cosas encadenadas o enlazadas. Tiene sentido decir `cadena de caracteres`, que en programación, no es más que un `string`.

Comment: @ArtEze El argumento que mencionas, "cadena no significa nada" no es correcto ya que el significado depende del contexto y de la comunidad. No es lo mismo hablar de cadenas entre joyeros, ferreteros y demás gremios de "hardware" cuando hablan de los productos que venden que hablar de cadenas entre programadores cuando se habla de tipos de datos. Siendo Stack Overflow en español una comunidad abierta a cualquiera que quiera colaborar en la temática del sitio resulta particularmente importante la orientación de uso de las etiquetas.

Comment: Por el momento, todas las preguntas que hablan sobre cadenas, se refieren al tipo de datos string. No le veo otro uso.